# "App is running" notification is shown using background_location plugin

Tags: android, flutter, notifications, navigation, geocoding

I needed to fetch location from the user even in the background. So for that I was using [background_location](https://pub.dev/packages/background_location).

```
await BackgroundLocation.setAndroidNotification(
  title: "XXXXx",
  message: "Accessing location",
  icon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher_rounded",
);
await BackgroundLocation.startLocationService();
BackgroundLocation.getLocationUpdates((location) {
  /*print("""\n
  Latitude:  ${location.latitude}
  Longitude: ${location.longitude}
  """);*/
  if (location != null) {
    if (currentLocation == null) {
      currentLocation = loc.LocationData.fromMap(
        {
          "latitude": location.latitude,
          "longitude": location.longitude,
        },
      );
      onLocationChanged();
      return;
    }
    if (currentLocation.latitude != location.latitude ||
        currentLocation.longitude != location.longitude) {
      currentLocation = loc.LocationData.fromMap(
          {"latitude": location.latitude, "longitude": location.longitude});
      onLocationChanged();
    }
  }
});
```

[image: this one]
There is no issue with fetching location but this notification is unnecessary. I am sure that this notification is shown when `await BackgroundLocation.startLocationService();` this line is executed. Little help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Plugin [background_location](https://pub.dev/packages/background_location) uses the [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services) to fetch the user's location in background.

> Foreground services perform operations that are noticeable to the
> user.
>
> Foreground services show a status bar notification so that users are
> actively aware that your app is performing a task in the foreground
> and is consuming system resources. The notification cannot be
> dismissed unless the service is either stopped or removed from the
> foreground.

---

You can change the notification title and description so that it's more understandable to the user.

```
BackgroundLocation.setAndroidNotification(
    title: "Notification title",
        message: "Notification message",
        icon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher",
);
```

Comment: this is not a fix ..!!

Comment: There is no fix , As stated by Android docs, if you run a foreground service,  notification is mandatory